# Import new Android module failure for JellyRefreshLayout module

Tags: java, android, import, module, java-8

I'm importing JellyRefreshLayout as modul (for some updates)

check this link : 
 **https://github.com/allan1st/JellyRefreshLayout**

but I always get this gradle build error :

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,

```
:app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :jellyrefresh:generateDebugSources, :jellyrefresh:mockableAndroidJar, :jellyrefresh:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :jellyrefresh:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
extractDebugAnnotations is incompatible with java 8 sources and has been disabled.
extractReleaseAnnotations is incompatible with java 8 sources and has been disabled.
:jellyrefresh:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:jellyrefresh:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:jellyrefresh:compileRetrolambdaRelease FAILED

Error:Execution failed for task ':jellyrefresh:compileRetrolambdaRelease'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':jellyrefresh:retrolambdaConfig'.
   > Could not resolve net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:2.0.3.
     Required by:
         JellyRefreshLayout-master:jellyrefresh:unspecified
      > No cached version of net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:2.0.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:2.0.3 available for offline mode.
```

project gradle build :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

App gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.co.imallan.jellyrefreshlayout"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile project(":jellyrefresh")
}
```

Library model :

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Note : my project JDK selection and Default JDK is:
***/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home***

Please Advice ! 
Thanks !

Comment: it's already unchecked man .

Comment: "offline mode " is at the end for error. invalidate cache and restart the studio.

Comment: I try it, but no thing done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's solved now .

The problem was : the internal_impl.jar is not on the retrolambda classpath sometimes.
because one of the following :

- because dependencies might be updated in 2nd execution.
- Maybe it is a bug in the Gradle Android plugin.

The Solution is : 
I run gradle cleaning and assembling in commands from gradle terminal befor syncing gradle :

***./gradlew clean assembleDebug***

from Gradle terminal .

please check this helpful conversation :

***https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/issues/105***